What is wrong with my derivation of this carry flag result for SUB?
To be clear, I am certain that the derivation below is incorrect, but I am hoping someone can point out where in my "proof" I am wrong.
I am trying to prove that the x86 instruction setb indeed implements x<y as an unsigned comparison when used after a cmp instruction. Specifically, let us consider (ATT syntax, and I will neglect suffixes indicting the number of bits)
# Compare two registers, e.g., %eax and %ebx with values y and x, respectively, when unsigned
cmp %ebx, %eax

# Set %al to 1 if %eax is below %ebx (unsigned comparison)
setb %al

The claim is that %al gets value 1 at the end of this if and only if the values of x,y obey x<y when considered as unsigned. We note that in the ATT syntax, the cmp instruction is subtracting the contents of %ebx from the contents of %eax and that this operation sets the relevant condition flags appropriately--including the carry out flag, which is of interest here. That is, it is putting the bit pattern into a subtractor unit to calculate x(-^u)y, where I use that notation to describe unsigned subtraction and I'll use - to describe subtraction of the corresponding integers.
Now here is my problem. Let's suppose x<y. We want to show that a carry out results from the subtraction. Suppose each number is w bits. I know (from my text, Bryant and O'Hallaron's CS:APP3e) that
x(-^u)y := x(+^u)((-^u) y) = x(+^u)(2^w - y) = 2^w + x - y < 2^w,

so ostensibly no carry out was obtained since the result fits into our w bits. That is, no carry out. This is just one direction of the "proof", but already I can clearly see I am wrong. Where am I going wrong though?

x86's sub and cmp set CF if there's a borrow from the subtraction.  This is the case if there's no carry-out from adding the inverse (with a carry-in of 1).  Some other ISAs (like ARM) are opposite of x86 for sub, seting their carry flag directly from the carry-out of a binary adder-subtractor.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder%E2%80%93subtractor .  Also related: Arithmetic identities and EFLAGS

Understood. So you are saying that when subtraction gets performed (presumably using the adder hardware while complementing the subtrahend and adding 1 to get the 2’s complement, as is standard in computer arch books) the adder/subtractor unit actually complements the carry output in the subtraction case, and that complemented carry is what we see as the CF flag? @PeterCordes

Yes for x86 and some other ISAs, unlike ARM and some others.

Super, thank you as always for your help! Happy to accept an answer to that effect as well if you'd like. @PeterCordes

I don't understand the precedence of =, := and < operators in your expression above.  Would you care to introduce parenthesis to make it clear?

My apologies, it was my intention to try to use standard mathematical notation but this site doesn't have MathJax so my attempt fell woefully short. FWIW, := is "equal by definition", = is equals, < is less than. That is, these are used in the math sense rather than in the programming language sense. @ErikEidt

x86's sub and cmp set CF if there's a borrow from the subtraction.  This is the case if there's no carry-out from adding the bitwise-inverse with a carry-in of 1, like the binary adder-subtractor in the ALU does.
Some ISAs (like ARM) are opposite of x86 for sub, set their carry flag directly from the carry-out of the adder-subtractor.  x86 (and some other ISAs) invert it.
Related: Arithmetic identities and EFLAGS - note that a correct asm equivalent to sub is a single add with carry-in of 1 and a cmc, not a separate neg and add, if you care about the EFLAGS result.
